# My webpage scraper works until I use it with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def hit_scraper(link):
    url = str(link)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/christianfreeman/Desktop/Social_Media/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    page = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    container = soup.find_all('span',attrs={"class":"ng-star-inserted"})
    container_list = str(list(container))
    pattern = r'#\S+'
    return re.findall(pattern,container_list)


df1['tags'] = [hit_scraper(i) for i in df1['extra_link']]
```

> InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument   (Session info: headless chrome=93.0.4577.63)

Comment: What do the values of `df1["extra_link"]` look like?

Comment: @blorgon website links. Stack overflow wont allow me to post the links

Comment: FWIW -- it doesn't look like you need chromedriver for what you're doing -- you could just use requests and get the html for the page directly

Answer (score 0):

If you're not navigating on the site I'd use requests instead of chromedriver:

```
    import requests

    def hit_scraper(link):
        page = requests.get(link).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        container = soup.find_all('span',attrs={"class":"ng-star-inserted"})
        container_list = str(list(container))
        pattern = r'#\S+'
        return re.findall(pattern,container_list)

    df1['tags'] = [hit_scraper(i, driver ) for i in df1['extra_link']]
```

With your existing code my suspicion is the chromedriver instance itself isn't exiting properly; perhaps try reusing the driver:

```
    def hit_scraper(link, driver):
        url = str(link)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        page = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        container = soup.find_all('span',attrs={"class":"ng-star-inserted"})
        container_list = str(list(container))
        pattern = r'#\S+'
        return re.findall(pattern,container_list)
    
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Users/christianfreeman/Desktop/Social_Media/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
    
    df1['tags'] = [hit_scraper(i, driver ) for i in df1['extra_link']]
    
    driver.quit()
```

quick aside, pandas has a mapper so you could also create the column as follows:

`df1.tags = df1.extra_link.apply(hit_scraper, axis=1)`

or (if you use the driver as an arg)

`df1.tags = drf1.extra_link.apply(hit_scraper, args=(driver,), axis=1)`